# Unable to load jakefile

Tags: javascript, node.js, jake

I just tried to make use of jake but found really weird issue that jake is unable to load jakefile. Do you have any idea how to resolve it.

Directory Structure:

> jake_test >> jake.sh
>
> jake_test >> jakefile.js

jake.sh file

```
node_modules/.bin/jake $*
```

Command to get log:

```
./jake.sh --trace
```

Here is trace log:

```
jake aborted.
Error: No Jakefile. Specify a valid path with -f/--jakefile, or place one in the current directory.
at api.fail (/opt/lampp/htdocs/jake_test/node_modules/jake/lib/api.js:336:18)
at EventEmitter.utils.mixin.run (/opt/lampp/htdocs/jake_test/node_modules/jake/lib/jake.js:319:9)
at Object. (/opt/lampp/htdocs/jake_test/node_modules/jake/bin/cli.js:25:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

Help really appriciated.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 13.10; jake version 8.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Actually, As I'm using case sensitive operating system so, 'jakefile.js' has to start with capital 'J'.

Thanks to James Shore.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Error:

```
jake aborted.  
Error: No Jakefile. Specify a valid path with -f/--jakefile, or place one in the current directory.
```

It's not able to find `Jakefile.js` in the current directory. In your case you have `jakefile.js` but this should be `Jakefile.js`. This will work on systems like Windows but with systems like *nix you will face this kind of problem.